# Error after converting Java to Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, I converted some code I had in java and stuck in one error.

here is the code

**Java Code:**

```
public abstract class BaseViewHolder<T extends BaseModel> extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
public T model;
    public BaseViewHolder(View view,BaseAdapter adapter) {
                    super(view);
                    adapter.select(BaseViewHolder.this);

    }
}
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder >  extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>  {

public void select(BaseViewHolder holder) {   }
}
```

**Kotlin code:**

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T : RecyclerView.ViewHolder> : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

fun select(holder: BaseViewHolder<BaseModel>) {
    }
}

abstract class BaseViewHolder<T : BaseModel?> : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

@JvmField
var model: T? = null

constructor(view: View, adapter: BaseAdapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>?) : super(view) {
    adapter.select(this@BaseViewHolder)  
            /// ERROR IS HERE type mismatch required BaseViewHolder<BaseModel> found BaseViewHolder<T>

}}
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: What is the `select` method supposed to do? The Java version is flawed to begin with because it uses a raw type. Raw types are always a code smell, so Kotlin forbids them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is what you're looking to achieve. Looking at your code I think that you want to specify that `BaseAdapter<T extends BaseModel>` not `BaseAdapter<T extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder >`.

Note: I agree with the comment by @Tenfour04 - your Java code contains raw types. Look how your constructor parameter here `public BaseViewHolder(View view,BaseAdapter adapter)` contains a `BaseAdapter` without the generics type as in `BaseAdapter<TYPE_GOES_HERE>`.

```
abstract class BaseAdapter<T : BaseModel> : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    fun select(holder: BaseViewHolder<T>) {
    }
}

abstract class BaseViewHolder<T : BaseModel> : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    @JvmField
    var model: T? = null

    constructor(view: View, adapter: BaseAdapter<T>) : super(view) {
        adapter.select(this@BaseViewHolder)
    }
}
```